# Use the 'cp' command in a Bash script and exclude a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, cp

I need to run this command in a shell script to **copy source > destination** and exclude a folder.

**No rsync, tar, find, mv, etc.**

Exactly this command:

`cp -var test/!(test2) testbkp`

1. In the shell it works
2. Run from a Bash script without exclude like `cp -var test testbkp` it works.

When I try to run from a Bash script with the exclude option

`cp -var test/!(test2) testbkp`, it doesn't work.

There isn't any output, nothing, and no error message.

I checked this post too, but no result:
[cp command won't run if executed from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328775/cp-command-wont-run-if-executed-from-shell-script)

How can I run this cp command in a Bash script and exclude folders?

Comment: `cp` is not part of bash -- it's a separate executable (typically something like `/usr/bin/cp`) you can use without any shell at all; so "bash 'cp' command" is somewhat misleading. On the other hand, it _is_ the shell responsible for taking a glob expression (like `test/!(test2)`) and generating a list of filenames from that expression before the `cp` executable (or whatever other executable you run) is started.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should enable the `extglob` option, it isn't enabled by default in scripts:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cp -var test/!(test2) testbkp
```

Also verify that the script is indeed running under bash.